# WYSIWYG editor that is intergrated with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have worked with Ruby on Rails for the last four years. So far I have used textmate for writing the code. This is working great as long as I don't need to do any decent presentation. I was wondering if there is any WYSIWYG editor out there that can intergrate with Rails. Something like Dreamweaver with the ability to browse Objects etc. If I have opened the _show.erb I create a div and selete @user.email. etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could look at Rubymine if your looking for an IDE...

Comment: I don't thing wysiwyg means what you think it means. If you're looking for something with code-completion, that's not wysiwyg, that's an IDE. How do you expect a wysiwyg editor to handle invoking your controller, evaluating your template, saving changes to a template vs a layout, etc?

Comment: I am looking for something that can assist with writing the html mockup. (all tags) And adjusting the CSS code. Looks like there is no such editor out there. So guess I will have to 1. Create the Design in Photoshop. 2. Build each uniq page in Dreamweaver. 3. Copy paste everything into templates and partials.

Comment: Why in the world would you have to build each unique page in dreamweaver?

Comment: @Chuck, I would build template pages for my website. Not every page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WYSIWYG editor for rails. You can edit HTML templates in a WYSIWYG editor, save them, append an ERB to the file name, and add in the code to make it function. That's not the same as WYSIWYG editing of a rails view though.

However, it sounds like what you're saying is you want to make something that looks pretty, and you feel that you need a WYSIWYG editor in order to be able to do that.

I would encourage you not to think that way. My opinion, for what it's worth, is that you're much more likely to create a beautiful design if the code underneath is, in fact, beautiful as well. Working in a WYSIWYG interface almost always results in terribly sloppy code that is quite hard to work with later on. You can definitely make amazing looking pages from raw code, you just need to work with a preview window open so you can get rapid feedback.

If you're on Mac a great IDE to use is [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/). It has preview, file browser, and terminal built in, so it's quite easy to get rapid feedback on how your code is "looking".

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to copy paste from a WYSIWYG to my Templates and views. At the moment I am wasting a lot of time writing views by hand and then previewing/checking the result with Firefox/firebug.

Comment: Try working with a live preview window in side-by-side view. I understand what you're saying, but as far as I know there simply isn't a WYSIWYG editor available that is capable of doing what you're describing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) if you're using OS X.

They offer point and click CSS editing and instant previews. Although not purely WYSIWYG, it still offers added convenience and suits most people fine.

Comment: I strongly recommend Coda as well, work in split view with a preview on one side and your code on the other.

Comment: Just tried Coda, and it looks like a solid editor. However it won't work with the previews. Setting up partials and views would be difficult and not better than textmate.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend Netbeans IDE or RubyMine (i'm using Netbeans for like 2 years now, it's just awesome)

Comment: RubyMine looks more like a flow blown IDE platform. At the moment I am using textmate and the terminal for that and this works very well. I need something that can help me with the views/css/partials.